# Printing all directories which contain a file containing a specific string

Tags: cmd

I'm new to cmd and am trying to find directories containing certain files. I have a few hundred directories to look through and some of them contain a file with the word `out` in the file, such as `Nov13bDout.txt`. Not all the directories contain a file with the string `out`, but some do and I'm trying to find which directories have this. Right now here's what I have:

```
@echo off
    setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

    set "folder=%~1"
    if not defined folder set "folder=%cd%"

    for /d %%a in ("%folder%\*") do (
        rem for /f in dir, if f=*out* then echo %%~nxa
    )

    endlocal
```

I'm still learning how to use cmd and am not sure how to write code for the commented part. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like the following:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

set "folder=%~1"
if not defined folder set "folder=%cd%"

for /D %%a in ("%folder%\*") do (
    rem // Reset flag variable initially:
    set "flag="
    rem /* Search for files containing `out` in their names;
    rem    if at least one is found, flag variable is set: */
    for %%b in ("%%~a\*out*.*") do set "flag=#"
    rem // Query whether flag variable has been set:
    if defined flag echo "%%~nxa"
)

endlocal
```